# Xamarin IOS custom control property doesn't displays

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've created my own custom control for my Xamarin.IOS application and I created a custom property for it. 
And I want to set value for it property in Visual Studio Properties toolbox, but no VS no Xcode doesn't display any custom properties.
I have to set custom Text kern spacing for custom buttons and I don't want to use any tricky or ugly ways to sort it out.

Here is my custom control code:

```
[Register("CustomButton"), DesignTimeVisible(true)]
    public class CustomButton : UIButton
    {
        private float _textLetterSpacing;

        protected internal CustomButton(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
        {
        }

        [Export("TextLetterSpacing"), Browsable(true)]
        public float TextLetterSpacing
        {
            get => _textLetterSpacing;
            set
            {
                _textLetterSpacing = value;
                SetNeedsDisplay();
            }
        }

        public CustomButton()
        {
            Initialize();

        }

        public override void AwakeFromNib()
        {
            // Called when loaded from xib or storyboard.
            Initialize();
        }

        void Initialize()
        {

              TextLetterSpacing = -0.49f;
            var title = this.Title(UIControlState.Normal);
            var attributedTitle = new NSAttributedString(title, new UIStringAttributes() { KerningAdjustment = TextLetterSpacing, ForegroundColor = this.CurrentTitleColor });
            this.SetAttributedTitle(attributedTitle, UIControlState.Normal);
            SetNeedsDisplay();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out this issue. 
There should `public` constructor instead of `protected internal`:

```
public CustomButton(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
{
}
```